# How to set PayloadXML in js in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2-esb

want to set a hard coded xml to message context (used js in WSO2 ESB) but getting error:
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing : after property id (#9) in  at line number 9

function sendStubResponse(mc) {

```
    var strFileContent   =  '<man:updateTSMTokenResponse xmlns:man="http://twodegreesmobile.co.nz/managetsmtoken"/>';
    mc.setPayloadXML({strFileContent});

  }
```

could you please suggest, how I can set PayloadXML in js with a variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
    var strFileContent = new XML(<man:updateTSMTokenResponse xmlns:man="http://twodegreesmobile.co.nz/managetsmtoken"/>);
    mc.setPayloadXML(strFileContent);
]]></script>
```

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks for your reply.. I need to read this static xml from a file. how can I read it from a file. "<man:updateTSMTokenResponse xmlns:man="http://twodegreesmobile.co.nz/managetsmtoken"/>" response will be there in a xml file located in conf folder